# Tear down and rebuild Core Data Stack with NSPersistentContainer

Tags: ios, core-data, restore

I felt sure that this question would have been asked and answered many times, but I was surprised to find that after hours of searching, I cannot find an answer. With the dawn of iOS 10, NSPersistentContainer changed the way we deal with the Core Data Stack. I understand how to set up a Core Data stack. But it is a different process to tear down and rebuild a Core Data stack when the underlying store is replaced (in my case, sqlite). I am hoping this is a stupid question and someone can point me to the 75 questions that I have somehow missed on this topic. Otherwise, I would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Generally you can't (or at least shouldn't) switch the store of persistentContainter.  If you want to delete all the data in the store - you should just do that.  If you have two different stores that represent two different things, then you should have two persistentContainters.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I implement Backup/Restore in my app. The user can restore data with data saved from a backup. I've done this for a couple of years (before iOS 10) by tearing down and rebuilding the Core Data stack, carefully, according to instructions I've found on Stack Overflow. I feel like the new methods provide a way to do this - I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you have been doing before should still work the same way.  A NSPersistentContainer is not magic, and does not do that much. It is a convenience for setting up a store with a model and a main thread context.  It is has methods for creating background context. It does not replace everything you know about core-data.  It is all the same stuff inside.  Inside the persistentContainer is a pointer to the persistentStoreCoordinator which has a pointer to the model and to the stores.

I don't know what you code is for replacing a store, so I can't help you translate it to a persistentContainer. If you find you can't do, there is no reason to stick to NSPersistentContainer, as I said before - it is not magic and it doesn't do that much for you.